# Is there a way to apply a sinewave distortion effect purely in shaders?

Tags: opengl, shader

Sinewave distortion of a 2D image is a classic visual effect: taking a 2D image and warping it along either the X or the Y axis by shifting pixels according to a sine wave.  It ends up looking something like this:
[image: Y-axis sinewave distortion example]

I've seen a few examples of code for it, and the standard way to do this with OpenGL seems to be, for a an image of dimensions (x, y):

```
for each column from 0 to X
  draw a single quad one pixel wide and y pixels high, offset by a sine wave value
```

Of course, this involves a lot of work on the client-side.  Is there any way to draw a single quad and offload the distortion work to the GPU with shaders?  Only vertex and fragment shaders; I'm using OpenGL 2, so there are no geometry shaders available.

I know I could use a fragment shader to sample texture coordinates that are offset by a sine wave, but getting them to place at locations outside the original box defined by the quad would be tricky, and I'd prefer not to have the output be clipped like in the sample picture.  Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: Does it need to be a quad or can you use other geometry?

Comment: Render a quad `2 * max_amplitude` taller and discard pixels that aren't currently being `sin()`'d onto?  That way you can reach "outside" your original quad.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this can be done using shaders. Using a vertex shader you can apply a sine distortion on a grid. A fragment shader can modulate the texture coordinate, but not the target pixel location; fragment shaders are *gatherers* and can not do data *scattering*.

#### Update

Working example for texture coordinate modulation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>

static void pushModelview()
{
    GLenum prev_matrix_mode;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MATRIX_MODE, &prev_matrix_mode);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(prev_matrix_mode);
}

static void popModelview()
{
    GLenum prev_matrix_mode;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_MATRIX_MODE, &prev_matrix_mode);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(prev_matrix_mode);
}

static const GLchar *vertex_shader_source =
"#version 130\n"
"void main()"
"{"
"   gl_Position = gl_ProjectionMatrix * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;"
"   gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;"
"   gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;"
"   gl_BackColor = gl_Color;"
"}\0";
GLuint shaderVertex = 0;

static const GLchar *fragment_shader_source = 
"#version 130\n"
"uniform sampler2D texCMYK;\n"
"uniform sampler2D texRGB;\n"
"uniform float T;\n"
"const float pi = 3.14159265;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   float ts = gl_TexCoord[0].s;\n"
"   vec2 mod_texcoord = gl_TexCoord[0].st + vec2(0, 0.5*sin(T + 1.5*ts*pi));\n"
"   gl_FragColor = -texture2D(texCMYK, mod_texcoord) + texture2D(texRGB, gl_TexCoord[0].st);\n"
"}\n\0";
GLuint shaderFragment = 0;

GLuint shaderProgram = 0;

#define TEX_CMYK_WIDTH 2
#define TEX_CMYK_HEIGHT 2
GLubyte textureDataCMYK[TEX_CMYK_WIDTH * TEX_CMYK_HEIGHT][3] = {
    {0x00, 0xff, 0xff}, {0xff, 0x00, 0xff},
    {0xff, 0xff, 0x00}, {0x00, 0x00, 0x00}
};
GLuint texCMYK = 0;

#define TEX_RGB_WIDTH 2
#define TEX_RGB_HEIGHT 2
GLubyte textureDataRGB[TEX_RGB_WIDTH * TEX_RGB_HEIGHT][3] = {
    {0x00, 0x00, 0xff}, {0xff, 0xff, 0xff},
    {0xff, 0x00, 0x00}, {0x00, 0xff, 0x00}
};
GLuint texRGB = 0;

GLfloat cube_vertices[][8] =  {
    /*  X     Y     Z   Nx   Ny   Nz    S    T */
    {-1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0}, // 0
    { 1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0}, // 1
    { 1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}, // 2
    {-1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0}, // 3

    { 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.0},
    {-1.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 1.0, 1.0},
    { 1.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0},

    {-1.0, -1.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
    {-1.0,  1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0},
    {-1.0,  1.0,  1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},

    { 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    { 1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
    { 1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0},
    { 1.0,  1.0, -1.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},

    { 1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
    {-1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0},
    { 1.0, -1.0,  1.0,  0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},

    {-1.0, 1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    { 1.0, 1.0,  1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
    { 1.0, 1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0},
    {-1.0, 1.0, -1.0,  0.0,  1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
};

static void draw_cube(void)
{
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 8, &cube_vertices[0][0]);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 8, &cube_vertices[0][3]);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat) * 8, &cube_vertices[0][6]);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
}

static void bind_sampler_to_unit_with_texture(GLchar const * const sampler_name, GLuint texture_unit, GLuint texture)
{
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + texture_unit); 
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        GLuint loc_sampler = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, sampler_name);
        glUniform1i(loc_sampler, texture_unit);
}

static void display(double T)
{
    int window_width, window_height;

    glfwGetWindowSize(&window_width, &window_height);
    if( !window_width || !window_height )
        return;

    const float window_aspect = (float)window_width / (float)window_height;

    glDisable(GL_SCISSOR_TEST);

    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.7, 1.0);
    glClearDepth(1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glViewport(0, 0, window_width, window_height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-window_aspect, window_aspect, -1, 1, 1, 100);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -5);

    pushModelview();
    glRotatef(T * 0.1 * 180, 0., 1., 0.);
    glRotatef(T * 0.1 *  60, 1., 0., 0.);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "T"), T);
    bind_sampler_to_unit_with_texture("texCMYK", 0, texCMYK);
    bind_sampler_to_unit_with_texture("texRGB", 1, texRGB);

    draw_cube();
    popModelview();

    glfwSwapBuffers();
}

static int open_window(void)
{
#if 0
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);
#endif

    if( glfwOpenWindow(0, 0,     /* default size */
                       8,  8, 8, /* 8 bits per channel */
                       8, 24, 8, /* 8 alpha, 24 depth, 8 stencil */
                       GLFW_WINDOW) != GL_TRUE ) {
        fputs("Could not open window.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    if( glewInit() != GLEW_OK ) {
        fputs("Could not initialize extensions.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

static int check_extensions(void)
{
    if( !GLEW_ARB_vertex_shader ||
        !GLEW_ARB_fragment_shader ) {
        fputs("Required OpenGL functionality not supported by system.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

static int check_shader_compilation(GLuint shader)
{
    GLint n;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &n);
    if( n == GL_FALSE ) {
        GLchar *info_log;
        glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &n);
        info_log = malloc(n);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, n, &n, info_log);
        fprintf(stderr, "Shader compilation failed: %*s\n", n, info_log);
        free(info_log);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

static int init_resources(void)
{
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_PIXELS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_SKIP_ROWS, 0);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH, 0);

    glGenTextures(1, &texCMYK);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texCMYK);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,  GL_RGB8, TEX_CMYK_WIDTH, TEX_CMYK_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureDataCMYK);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glGenTextures(1, &texRGB);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texRGB);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,  GL_RGB8, TEX_RGB_WIDTH, TEX_RGB_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureDataRGB);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    shaderVertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(shaderVertex, 1, (const GLchar**)&vertex_shader_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shaderVertex);
    if( !check_shader_compilation(shaderVertex) )
        return 0;

    shaderFragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(shaderFragment, 1, (const GLchar**)&fragment_shader_source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(shaderFragment);
    if( !check_shader_compilation(shaderFragment) )
        return 0;

    shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, shaderVertex);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, shaderFragment);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    return 1;
}

static void main_loop(void)
{
    glfwSetTime(0);
    while( glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED) == GL_TRUE ) {
        display(glfwGetTime());
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if( glfwInit() != GL_TRUE ) {
        fputs("Could not initialize framework.\n", stderr);
        return -1;
    }

    if( !open_window() )
        return -1;

    if( !check_extensions() )
        return -1;

    if( !init_resources() )
        return -1;

    main_loop();

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

The fragment shader part is this:

```
#version 130
uniform sampler2D texCMYK;
uniform sampler2D texRGB;
uniform float T;
const float pi = 3.14159265;
void main()
{
    float ts = gl_TexCoord[0].s;
    vec2 mod_texcoord = gl_TexCoord[0].st + vec2(0, 0.5*sin(T + 1.5*ts*pi));
    gl_FragColor = -texture2D(texCMYK, mod_texcoord) + texture2D(texRGB, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
};
```

#### Update – a shader that "expands":

```
uniform sampler2D texCMYK;
uniform sampler2D texRGB;
uniform float T;
const float pi = 3.14159265;
void main()
{
   float ts = gl_TexCoord[0].s;
   vec2 mod_texcoord = gl_TexCoord[0].st*vec2(1., 2.) + vec2(0, -0.5 + 0.5*sin(T + 1.5*ts*pi));
   if( mod_texcoord.t < 0. || mod_texcoord.t > 1. ) { discard; }
   gl_FragColor = -texture2D(texCMYK, mod_texcoord) + texture2D(texRGB, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
};
```

Comment: How do I apply the distortion on the grid if all I have is four vertices and no geometry shader?

Comment: @MasonWheeler: In the case of only 4 vertices, a vertex shader will not do the trick. But you can still use a fragment shader to modulate the texture coordinate.

Comment: What's the CMYK stuff in there for?

Comment: @genpfault: Those are just two textures. Both 2×2 pixels. The one has a red pixel, a green pixel, a blue pixel and a white pixel (that's the RGB texture), the other containy a cyan pixel, a magenta pixel, a yellow pixel and a black pixel, (that's the CMYK texture). You can see the texture date immediately after the shader source codes in the full code pasting.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were trying to do some funky colorspace conversion stuff somewhere, rather than just having some small inline sample textures.  That makes much more sense.

Comment: Thanks for the sample shader code. Unfortunately, it doesn't meet the requirement of having the output image not be clipped to the rectangle defined by the size of the input quad.  But it's a good first step.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: Make the rectangle bigger than the undistorted size. Then either discard pixels outside the distortion, or set their alpha value to zero and enable blending. Sorry I can't give you an example right now, because (Murphy) apparently the GPU in my development machine just died… anyway I modified the shader source a bit.

Answer (score 4):

For a given input quad render a quad `2 * max_amplitude` taller (maybe with a vertex shader?) and in your pixel shader discard pixels that aren't currently being `sin()`'d onto.

That way you can reach "outside" your original quad.

Comment: Hmm... so if I use the vertex shader to scale the size of the output quad up according to the amplitude of the sine wave distortion, then the input coordinates I get in the fragment shader would be in distorted space, and I'd have to calculate the sine wave formula *backwards* to find the correct original texels to sample.  Is that right?